# highcharts basics

Tags: highcharts

I have the following data fetched in the array using php and my sql

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
        )

    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 1
                    [2] => 2
                    [3] => 3
                    [4] => 4
                    [5] => 5
                    [6] => 6


                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 34
                    [1] => 35
                    [2] => 36
                    [3] => 37
                    [4] => 38
                    [5] => 39
                    [6] => 40

                )

        )

)
```

I am new to highcharts and jquery.

The function for the line plot is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'line',
                marginRight: 130,
                marginBottom: 25
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        this.x +': '+ this.y +'°C';
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -10,
                y: 100,
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
            }, {
                name: 'New York',
                data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
            }, {
                name: 'Berlin',
                data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
            }, {
                name: 'London',
                data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
            }]
        });
    });

});
        </script>
```

I don't know how to pass my data for a and b so that it can line plot
Need it urgent .. thanks

Comment: The thing you want to go in the X-axis, put it in the `categories` array for `xAxis`. Your values go in `series`

Comment: @burhad: thanks for the reply..but how to parse my data in the specified format. to pass in series

Comment: Its a javascript array of numbers; you also have a series of numbers. Simply convert it to a javascript array.

Comment: i am unable to parse it into the specified format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following to get your array parsed to js.

```
var data = jQuery.parseJSON(' <?php echo json_encode($yourArray, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?> ');
```

Than you can put it inside your serie like the following.

```
series: [{
    'name': data.name[0],
    'data': data.data[0]
}, {
    'name': data.name[1],
    'data': data.data[1]
}]
```